# Returning array values (image file names to javascript) from php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Hi I have a php file which is reading all the image files in a directory as so:

```
    <?php

$dir = "Images/";
$arrayjs = array();

// Open a directory, and read its contents
if (is_dir($dir)){
  if ($dh = opendir($dir)){
    while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false){
    if($file != "." && $file != ".."){
         $arrayjs[] = $file;
        echo "filename:" . $file . "<br>";
    }
    }
    closedir($dh);
  }
}

header('Content-type:application/json;charset=utf-8'); 
 echo json_encode($arrayjs);
?>
```

and I want to get the resulting array in javascript. This code is not working. Any idea why?

```
 <script type = "text/javascript">
 $(function() {
    $.getJSON('fileNames.php', function(data) {
        console.log('yaa');
        $(data).each(function(key, value) {
            console.log(value);
        });
    });
});


    </script>
```

Comment: `echo "filename:" . $file . "<br>";` is breaking the json formatting

Comment: wow thanks did not know that

Answer (score 0):

getJson performs an ajax call, which will read the contents of the file as its written/displayed, so your `echo "filename:" . $file . "<br>";` is becoming part of that meaning your json is becoming invalid

comment out that line and you should be fine

```
 <?php

$dir = "Images/";
$arrayjs = array();

// Open a directory, and read its contents
if (is_dir($dir)){
  if ($dh = opendir($dir)){
    while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false){
    if($file != "." && $file != ".."){
         $arrayjs[] = $file;
        //echo "filename:" . $file . "<br>";
    }
    }
    closedir($dh);
  }
}

header('Content-type:application/json;charset=utf-8'); 
 echo json_encode($arrayjs);
?>
```

The method wants nothing but valid json to be echo'd/displayed